# importing dask_cuda results in parse_memory_limit error

Tags: python, cuda, conda, dask, distributed

I'm trying to import dask_cuda as the examples:

```
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask_cuda/__init__.py:5, in <module>
      2 import dask.dataframe.shuffle
      4 from ._version import get_versions
----> 5 from .cuda_worker import CUDAWorker
      6 from .explicit_comms.dataframe.shuffle import get_rearrange_by_column_tasks_wrapper
      7 from .local_cuda_cluster import LocalCUDACluster

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask_cuda/cuda_worker.py:19, in <module>
     14 from distributed.proctitle import (
     15     enable_proctitle_on_children,
     16     enable_proctitle_on_current,
     17 )
     18 from distributed.utils import parse_bytes
---> 19 from distributed.worker import parse_memory_limit
     21 from .device_host_file import DeviceHostFile
     22 from .initialize import initialize

ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_memory_limit' from 'distributed.worker' (/home/shambakey1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py)
```

I googled this error, but couldn't find anything related to it. I thought it was a DASK problem, so I re-tried with only `from dask.distributed import Client`, and it worked. So, I guess this error is related to dask_cuda, but I don't know how.

The version I have are:

1. dask-cuda -> 22.6.0
2. dask -> 2021.12.0
3. distributed -> 2021.12.0
4. Ubuntu 20.04

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dask version is rather old, the `parse_memory_limit` was added fairly recently in 2022, see [this PR](https://github.com/rapidsai/dask-cuda/pull/870).

I would recommend not pinning dask and let `conda` find the most suitable version. If that's not an option, then `dask=2022.7.0` works for me with `dask-cuda=2022.6.0`.